# how to add custom culomn to add user wordpress in plugin

Tags: plugins

I want to add a custom column called balance for each user and I want to be able to update this column by adding value or subtracting value from it, and I want to do that by a plugin I create, any ideas ??

[image: in this]

I used this code but the balance field doesn't show when I want to add a new user

```
  '<?php 
/**
 * Plugin Name: add_col
 * Description : plugin adds new column to user info
 */
 
 function new_contact_methods( $contactmethods ) {
    $contactmethods['balance'] = 'balance';
    return $contactmethods;
}
add_filter( 'user_contactmethods', 'new_contact_methods', 10, 1 );


function new_modify_user_table( $column ) {
    $column['balance'] = 'balance';
    return $column;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'new_modify_user_table' );

function new_modify_user_table_row( $val, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    switch ($column_name) {
        case 'balance' :
            return get_the_author_meta( 'balance', $user_id );
        default:
    }
    return $val;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'new_modify_user_table_row', 10, 3 );
```

'

Comment: You can store the balance in the user meta table, using update_user_meta and get_user_meta.

Comment: can you explain more??

Comment: You also asked about inputting the value on this form: for that you'll need to hook [user_new_form](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_new_form/).

Comment: @Rup I added the code I found but it doesn't get the job done

Comment: Contact methods would work, but it would show the balance on the user's own 'edit user' page, which I guess you wouldn't want. When you said user table I assumed you meant database table: I don't know about the users table in the admin site.

Comment: As I said, if you want to add the balance to the 'add user' form you'll need to hook user_new_form. (Or network_user_new_form if this is a multisite WordPress.)

Comment: thaaaanks you helped me a lot @Rup